# Script Parse Exception with python elasticsearch API

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I wrote the following code to set a template for new indexes:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

doc = {
   "template": "te*",
  "settings": {
     "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
     "type1": {
      "_source": {
         "enabled": "false"
       },
      "properties": {
        "host_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }

 es = Elasticsearch([{'host': "127.0.0.1", "port": 9200}])
 es.put_template("f_1", body=doc)
```

The following error looks like some syntax error i can't solve:

> launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>   File "/Users/D/workspace/es_index_template/create_schema.py", line 31,
>   in 
>   es.put_template("freshmilk_1", body=doc)   File "/Users/D/.virtualenvs/es_index_template/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py",
>   line 69, in _wrapped
>   return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)   File "/Users/D/.virtualenvs/es_index_template/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py",
>   line 1152, in put_template
>   'template', id), params=params, body=body)   File "/Users/D/.virtualenvs/es_index_template/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py",
>   line 329, in perform_request
>       status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)   File
>   "/Users/D/.virtualenvs/es_index_template/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py",
>   line 109, in perform_request
>       self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)   File "/Users/D/.virtualenvs/es_index_template/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py",
>
> line 108, in _raise_error
>       raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
>   elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500,
>   u'script_parse_exception', u'unexpected field [mappings]')

Has someone an idea why he fails with the mappings?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Loïc: "2.1.1" Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I took the put_template method as a query template but its meant to be a index template:
Library usage should look like this:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': "127.0.0.1", "port": 9200}])
IndicesClient(es).put_template(name="f_1", body=request_body)
```